# MYSQL stored procedure arithmetic addition amount every number

Tags: php, mysql

already have the code in php,
but I want implement it to mysql stored procedure?

this my php code:

```
$array = [];
$amount = 0;
$add = 20;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    $amount += $add;
    $array[] = $amount;
}

print_r($array);
result : [20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200];
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(327) DEFAULT '';
    
    REPEAT
        SET result = CONCAT(result,counter,',');
        SET counter = counter + 20;
    UNTIL counter >= 10
    END REPEAT;
    
    -- display result
    SELECT result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but that didn't work

Comment: First `SET counter = counter + 20;` makes your `counter` value equal to 21, and due to `UNTIL counter >= 10` the cycle is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE result TEXT;
    
    REPEAT
        SET result = CONCAT_WS(',', result,counter * 20);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    UNTIL counter >= 10
    END REPEAT;
    
    -- display result
    SELECT result;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/XJfYfXiV